# find all files and folders which have specific owner/group with grep

Tags: command-line, grep

In `home/oracle` I have many files and folders.

I need 2 different codes to:

- find (show) all files and folders belongs to user "Jim" from group "app"
- Change user owner of all files and folders from (Jim) to Harry.

Is it possible to do it with `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man find xargs chown` and do something like (**Untested**)

```
find /home/oracle \( -user Jim -a -group app \) -print0 | \
  xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty \
    echo sudo chown Harry
```

Remove the `echo` after testing.

You can't do it with `grep`. `grep` searches the content of files, you want to check and modify the files' metadata.